# How to use function view in Drupal

Tags: drupal, view

I am trying to learn how to create my own module and I am stuck. I created text.module, text.install and text.info . It's just a basic module for inputing text.

So now I have the next scenario I input the text in textbox,  it saves to a table in the database i can display it into a table like in this:

http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/5815/textyi.jpg

now my question is can you and how can you use function view so that in the picture "ttt" becomes a link so that you can see the title and text "ttt" ?

EDIT :

I figure out something i just need this :

in table I have 3 columns (test_id, title, text)

Now i use

```
$result = db_query("select title,text from {text} ");
```

now how can I turn title into a link . Let say that in row 1 col1 of title it stands house. How can i turn house into a link. Do i need to do sometning like this

```
$result= db_query ("select n.title, n.text form {text} n where n.title = :title", array (":title" => ???? ))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
<?php
l(t('Link text'), 'about-us', array('attributes' => array('class' => 'about-link')));
?>
```

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/l/7 might help u..